# How to deal with different input sizes in CNN models

Tags: image, tensorflow, computer-vision, image-recognition

To give a bit of a context: I'm fairly new to machine learning, I've read and seen some educational videos on how CNN works.

I've tried two models so far, a random person's CNN model and the Google's Inception v3 model. I could understand that random's person CNN model and what's happening in there. What I don't understand is how to make it work with different output sizes that are not just a different scale or rotation. Let me just explain what I'm doing:

I basically want to be able to classify a picture (containing a logo) as a brand. For example, you give me a picture that contains the Starbucks logo and our model will tell you it's Starbucks. There is going to be only one logo in every picture (for my case). First try was with the inception model: tried with 20,000 iterations with 2,000 Starbucks receipt pictures, 2,000 Walmart receipt pictures and 2,000 random pictures that were not related to Starbucks or Walmart so I could also classify the picture as 'Neither'. Got 88% accuracy, not good enough and the cross entropy doesn't drop to lower than 0.4 then I tried cropping the logo from those picture and tried again. this time, on cropped pictures it would work like a charm but on bigger pictures containing the starbucks logo, or walmart for that matter, it would fail miserably.

Same thing with the DeepLogo's way: https://github.com/satojkovic/DeepLogo

It works well with the 32 x 32 picture but once I change the input size, it fails.

How can I overcome this?

**EDIT**: I'm using this for retraining on top of the Inception model: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining

Comment: Let us say that your network takes 128 x 128 image. Once you get an image, resize its shorter side to 128 and keep the aspect ratio. The take various (labeled) crops of size 128 x 128 to train a fully convolutional neural network on different crops of the image. At the last layer, you can append average/max pooling and then one FC layer as a classifier.

Comment: When using CNNs your input images should always be the same size as you have trained your network for finding features on images of this size. The output of the network is also the same size in all cases as you define a structure for your network, with sizes.
But you could resize the image and pad them to remain the same aspect ratio.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar ah I see, so basically traverse the picture. I'll definitely try that but I have a question for it: let's say my logo is 128 x 128 and all of my training data is 128 x 128. Now I have a 1024 x 256 picture and that logo, with the same size (128 x 128) exists in this picture, if I keep the aspect ratio and resize, it'll make the logo smaller and I won't be able to classify it. right?

Comment: In that case maybe you should extract 128 x 128 patches and slide a fully-convolutional network across the entire image. If you receive a positive prediction in either one of those patches, then you classify that image as a positive. There may be a lot of false positives when you do detection this way.

Answer (score 1):

Pooling layer? 
From my understanding, pooling layer improves the statistical efficiency and also translation invariance. And most important, in your case, it can be used in various size of images.
Maybe you could do some research on that. The book "Deep Learning" from Goodfellow would be my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation, so for the simplicity, let's say I trained on a set of 128 x 128 pictures, now I want to see if one of these logos exist in a 1024 * 860 picture, should I traverse the picture and see if I can it? how would I know to resize? I can certainly keep the same aspect ratio but that would make the logo too small in this picture.